# SVN tagging equivalent in TFS 2012

Tags: svn, tags, checkpoint

I recently migrated to the **TFS 2012** and I have worked with **SVN** for a long time.

In SVN I used "*Tags*" to mark some important "*checkpoints*" of development, ie when I finished a software version (alpha, beta) I created a *Tag* for that version. If some mistake happen, I am "*protected*".

Now, I need the same behaviour (or equivalent) to use in the **TFS** source control, but I'm confused as to its structure.

How I use "*Tagging*" in **TFS**?

Comment: You probably want a label: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475879(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yeah! "Snapshot". I didnt remember this word. Its exactly what I need. Thanks. Post it as answer: I want to vote up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Team Foundation Server, [labels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475879%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are similar to tags in other version control system; a label contains files at a specific version.

When we release some product, we snapshot the entire team project as a label - that is to say that we create some label `11_Release` to point to our 11.0.0 release, and it will contain `$/TEE` (our Team Project) at version Latest.  We then unthaw the branch and allow check-ins to proceed.

Exactly how this works will depend on your process, of course.  You need not necessarily apply the latest version to that label, it could, in fact, be some other changeset or even date version spec.

Comment: One thing to note: labels don't have history. This can be a compliance issue in some industries.

Comment: aclear16, even without history, can I see the others "automatic labels" created when I checked in a file? All them would be a "history"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to TFS but "Labels" are indeed the equivalent for as far as I know. You have to keep in mind though that they aren't the same thing as tags though. A label is really just a name for a snapshot of the files in TFS.

There is no separate branch for a tag like in SVN. In other words, if you have a tag "v 1.0" in SVN, then you can still checkin changes to it in case you need to make a small fix or addition. In TFS this is not possible with labels.

Answer (score 0):

As Ron Mentioned TFS labels also very similar to Tags and it will not create a separate branch like in SVN.

But Ron had mentioned that you can not add small changes to that label, actually you can. If you want to make a change on a file of that label then you can check in that change and after that you can edit the previously created label to include that new check in version.

Simply you can edit the versions of files that bundled into a label later also.