# TFS Code Versioning

Tags: git, tfs, version-control, versioning

We use TFS for source control and would like to control source versions.

For example, we sell our app which is MyProduct 1.0 to a customer, but the customer has not buy maintanance support, that means we are not giving an updated version of the MyProduct.

Well, after a while, we have been developing MyProduct 2.6 and then at the same time, the customer realises there is a bug in MyProduct 1.0. So they ask for a bug fix. As mentionend earlier, we have been developing version 2.6 and there is no code for 1.0 anymore.

I know that TFS has history feauture but I cant see there versions, it is only based on commits.

If we consider Github that provides Releases (code) with versions. Such as

[image]

Well when i click "Releases" menu, i can see all code releases with versions and i can download what i want as SOURCE CODE.

So has TFS that kind of feature?

Secondly, we use also TFS builds. Is it possible to create builds according the versions? For example, If i have myproduct 1.0 and myproduct 2.6, i will be able to create build for any version that i want.

PS: We do not want to create bunch of branches!

Comment: "PS: We do not want to create bunch of branches!" Um, you really _do_. Otherwise you just end up manually creating branches that *aren't in source control*.

Comment: check github, with only master branch, you can create many releases (source code).. i dont know why we cant do that in TFS even we pay for it.

Comment: github releases are (essentially) just tags. TFS calls tags "labels"; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/15790073/8446

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS supports creating tags for history commits in VS, and you can push the tag to TFS with command line `git push --tags` (currently there’s no a default option in VS 2015 IDE to push commit tags):

[image]

After creating tags, you'll see them on the right of history:

[image]

Regarding build, you can specify the commit you want to build when queue a build:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works for me. The only problem, when i create a build, i cant select a certain commit. It only shows branches. But with queue it is fine even i cant see Commit Id.. From the branch, I can see Tags and i can select the version tag.

Comment: Yes I know what you mean. Check this picture please https://s14.postimg.org/t3w0w5c9d/07_10.png